# In Taiwan, what do you call those covered walkways?

Tags: terminology, taiwan, architecture

From what I've seen, Taiwan doesn't really have sidewalks. Instead, people walk "under" buildings.

Is there a name for that gap space, between the street and the building fronts?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, the space is called a [five foot way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_foot_way) in SE Asia:

> Although it looks like European arcade along the streets, it is a building feature that suits the local climate, and characterizes the town-scape and urban life of this region.

And the buildings that have this sort of space are called [qilou](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qilou).

Comment: Interesting. I did not think to call them anything but they were immensely useful in Taiwan and when I told people that, they were surprised that it's not like that everywhere else!

Comment: @Itai useful but slippery :-/

Comment: +1 I've known about it but never knew what they were called.